# I need to add current date to firebase Realtime database in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**STATE OF CURRENT DATE**

```
const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date())
    console.log('date', date);
```

**DATE CAN'T PUSHED TO FIREBASE DATABASE AND HOW TO PUSH DATE IN REALTIME DATABASE.**

```
 function addNewPerson() {
        push(ref(db, '/addperson'), {
            //   addperson: value,
            //    value,
            'Name': name,
            'Room_no': selectedRoomNo,
            'Contact': contact,
            'Address': address,
            'Image': fetchImage,
            'Advanced_amount': advancedAmount,
            'Date': date,
        });
        // setPresentTodo('');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add like below:

```
function addNewPerson() {
    push(ref(db, '/addperson'), {
        //   addperson: value,
        //    value,
        'Name': name,
        'Room_no': selectedRoomNo,
        'Contact': contact,
        'Address': address,
        'Image': fetchImage,
        'Advanced_amount': advancedAmount,
        'Date': new Date().toUTCString(),
    });
    // setPresentTodo('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` is a function you can't directly store the date function you need to convert it into a string and then it can be stored in the database

```
new Date().toISOString()
```